# Pyglet fails to load swrast_dri.so in Python 3 (Anaconda) when running on a headless server with Xvfb

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, pyglet, xvfb, pyopenssl

This works fine in python 2.7, but it fails in python 3.5 (Anaconda):

```
$ xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" ./anaconda2/envs/python3/bin/python

Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from pyglet.gl import gl_info

libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (...)
  File "(...)/pyglet/gl/gl_info.py", line 92, in set_active_context
    self.vendor = asstr(cast(glGetString(GL_VENDOR), c_char_p).value)
  File "(...)/pyglet/compat.py", line 88, in asstr
    return s.decode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

It seems that for some reason it can't load `swrast_dri.so`.  I tried adding the path to that library:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But this did not help. Any idea?

Note: I'm running on Debian:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.6
```

**Edit**

I just checked, everything works fine with the system python 3. So it seems to be an issue with the combination of Anaconda + the system's opengl libraries.  I'm guessing they were not compiled with the same standard libraries or something.  I tried running:

```
$ conda install -n python3 pyopengl
```

Installation went fine but I still get the same bug.